# Blastp MSA to the same length

Tags: python, blastp

To generate aligned protein sequence truncate to the same length, I use blastp in biopython for MSA. I have multiple queries and one subject sequence. However, the alignment never returns the same length.

How can I align all sequences altogether, thus resulting in a set of sequences of the same length?

Comment: Please consider accepting/upvoting the answers below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Matteo Ferla wrote in the comments,

> It sounds like you'd want a MSA of the whole set and not a set of pairwise ones. If global MSA is what you actually want, try ebi.ac.uk/Tools/msa/muscle. Then to trim the ends before phylogeny there are dozens of tools.

> The reason is because Blast aligns locally, i.e. a window, while a global alignment is the whole entirety of the sequence

Answer (score 2):

BLAST isn't appropriate for multiple sequence alignment.
BLAST generates pairwise alignments. Furthermore, the aligning regions shown in a BLAST report only include subsets of the hit sequences.

To create multiple sequence alignment of hits you want to:

- run blast
- extract the hit sequences
- perform multiple-sequence-alignment (e.g., using MAFFT)

Extracting hit sequences can be done using the command-line. Check the docs for `blastdbcmd`.

If you prefer a point-and-click interface, you can also do this using my lab's [SequenceServer BLAST software](https://sequenceserver.com) by simply selecting the hits that you want to retain, and in the **Download** section, clicking "FASTA of selected hits". Or if you want all of them, click "FASTA of all hits".

[image: Download hits from BLAST report]

Comment: Please add a statement stating that your lab created this software that you're posting about on multiple threads.